# Replacing HTML entities in Go strings

Tags: html, go

What is the most straightforward way to replace HTML entities with their string representations in a Go `string`? That is, how would I turn the string `R&oslash;&d gr&oslash;d &amp; fl&oslash;de` into `Rød grød & fløde`?

My own solutions have been either using `strings.Replace` on all relevant entities (which quickly becomes intractable), or wrapping the string into an XML document and decoding it with `xml.Decoder` (which seems silly and leads to numerous edge cases).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the [html.UnescapeString](https://godoc.org/html#example-UnescapeString) function:

```
fmt.Println(html.UnescapeString("R&oslash;&d gr&oslash;d &amp; fl&oslash;de"))
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/lqK4Jvs6qJ)

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Knew the standard libraries had to have something.